# Double Revival: Techiyat HaMeitim!

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

It seems [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3780/759) has produced two [revival](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/badges/59/revival) badges: [one for Menachem](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/badges/59/revival?userid=603) and [one for Alex](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/badges/59/revival?userid=37). I didn't think that was possible.

Comment: You might wish to edit into the question any information you have about when the users got their badges, how many votes they had (for their respective answers) at the time, etc., which may help people track down the bug.

Comment: @msh210 The links I give tell exactly when the badges were given.

Comment: For any SE employees or others who come across this, Techiyat Hameitim is revival of the dead. (Just a pun, not important to the question.)

Answer (score 3):

Alex's answer now has 3 upvotes and no downvotes. According to his reputation history, he got an upvote on that answer today, and one yesterday, and no other votes on it since June 21. Thus, on June 22, his answer had but one upvote. At that time, Menachem's answer earned him the Revival badge ("…first answer scoring 2 or more"), which makes sense, since it was the only answer scoring two or more at that time. Then, Alex's answer got its second (and third) upvotes, making it the "first answer scoring 2 or more", since it was actually posted earlier than Menachem's was so is "first".

Comment: ?? Alex got his badge yesterday I think

Comment: Oh, I misread that. Yeah, this answer is wrong. Deleting.

Comment: I'm undeleting this, since you're really correct for the most part. When Menachem's answer had two upvotes, Alex' had only one, so Menachem got the badge. Only then did Alex' answer get the second upvote, so suddenly *his* answer (because it's the older one) was the one eligible for the badge, and thus he got it. While Menachem's answer now isn't eligible for the badge anymore, we don't take badges away once they're awarded. Similar example: If you get a nice question badge, but then get downvoted to only have +9, you keep the badge as well.

Comment: @balpha Sorry I'm still not understanding. Wasn't Menachem's the first answer to receive 2 votes? It shouldn't matter which is older. I think??

Comment: @DoubleAA You could say it's a philosophical question, but the point of the revival badge is rewarding a good answer posted to a tumbleweed question. So the important question is "When was the answer posted?" I can see the direction you're coming from as well, but that's how we define the badge. And, for what it's worth, a) what happened here is an extreme edge case anyway, and b) two people got badges for two good answers, which is fine for me :)

Comment: I've edited the answer to be correct, in light of balpha's comments. Thanks, @balpha.

Comment: @balpha So the badge process checks repeatedly for any answer that has 2 votes, was posted 30 days after the question, and has no older answer with 2 votes? If so that isn't readily apparent from the description on the badge page.

Comment: FTR the text from [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68258/166155) is: Answer a question 30 days after it is asked and have that answer be the first one for that question to reach a score of two

Comment: @msh210 Are you satisfied with balpha's explanation? I'm still kinda confused.

Comment: @DoubleAA, the documentation at the MSO post you linked to above was wrong (I've just edited it for accuracy), and the explanation on /badges is still wrong, but balpha's explanation is clear enough, yes.